# How to create Import Definition using FuelSDK Python

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, python

I'm able to create a new data extension and import few records using FuelSDK for python. However, I want to create a import definition and use that to import files from FTP site instead of manually loading the files using python. I see PHP, C#,  and Java samples on salesforce website (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_an_import_definition.htm) but nothing using python.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Need to add following to objects.py.

class ET_Import(ET_CUDSupport):
    def **init**(self):
        super(ET_Import, self).**init**()
        self.obj_type = 'ImportDefinition'